# Can't add a font to a custom email template salesforce

Tags: css, email, fonts, salesforce

I've been trying for a while to add a custom font to a custom email template. The issue is the following:

on the preview screen, the text font is correct and I see the email as it should be; whenever I send the email to any address, the font doesn't get loaded and the font I see is Arial.

I tried to:

- use different providers (gmail, outlook webmail, outlook desktop client)
- bind the font directly to the email template in base 64
- link the font via a static resource (instead of linking it using a public document)
- using slightly different approaches (single quote, double quotes, and so on)
- put the ttf on a different host (which doesn't have any restrictions due to .htaccess)
  As far as I know, the solution I'm trying to implement should not work for all the browsers, but since I didn't manage to get it work so far for Chrome, I'm not focusing on this problem right now.

Here's a snippet of the html + css code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: 'GillSans';
   src: url('https://c.cs20.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015m0000000DhgX') format('truetype') ;
}
body {
   letter-spacing: 4pt;
   word-spacing: 0.25em;
}
p {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 24px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-family: GillSans;
}
</style>
<title>WELCOME</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
SOME TEXT GOES HERE
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your font is stored on Force.com servers.  Depending on the email client your recipient uses, whether she has a Salesforce account, your security restrictions, etc. they won't be able to download.  Try putting the font file on a public file storage server that doesn't require a login.